# How do I write a script that will pull info from an open tab in Chrome into Mainframe?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, vbscript, extra

I am very very green & have almost no experience in coding. Usually I record a macro & then tweak it to do exactly what I want. However, I am trying to create a script (either *.bzs, *.bbs, *.bbh, *.vbs, *.js, *.ebm) that can pull a single piece of data from an open tab in **Chrome**. We use **BlueZone Mainframe Display** at a call center & I'm trying to pull up customer information when they enter it into our phone system which is **Cisco Finesse** run on Chrome. As of now we have to copy & paste it from one screen to another & I'm looking to automate that. In theory I feel like this should be very possible but don't know where to start. Please help!

Answer (score 1):

What you're probably looking for is a Chrome extension. Chrome extensions have the ability to interact with multiple tabs in a browser window--e.g. copy data from one tab and paste it into another. However, without much programming knowledge, this is going to take quite a bit of effort on your part.

Here are some resources to get you started:

- https://github.com/orbitbot/chrome-extensions-examples
- https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/getstarted

Comment: Thank you very much. I've considered that as well. I know I'm reaching pretty high for not having much knowledge but I'm not afraid of the work involved. Just really trying to get some direction & make sure I'm not busting my butt for something that I don't know is actually impossible. Thank s again. I'll start researching Chrome extensions.